# VLAN routing to internet

Tags: routing, vlan, ios, switch, networking

I am currently setting up a new network and wanted to make sure it is being done in the best way as this is my first time working on a NetVanta 1234P and I am having issues with routing

The client I am setting up for is a building with 100 different offices in it, each office would like there own SSID and have there own subnet, IP address scheme being used is 172.16.1-100.0 /24 (3rd octet increments for each client/subnet). The device which will be managing the wireless is a Rukus ZoneDirector 1000, I have already created 100 SSIDs in it as well as VLANs 1001-1100.

The Switch that is being used is a Adtran Netvanta 1234P, I have already created the 100 different vlans (1001-1100) but found a limitation of assigning IP addresses to those VLAN interfaces, seems like I am only able to assign up to 15 IPs to virtual interfaces (please correct me if I am wrong..).

Essentially what i am looking for is routing to work for each SSID which is on its own VLAN, I have set the ports to which the Zonedirector and APs connect to as trunked. As of now, I am unable to hit my WatchGuard IP from any of the trunked ports, is there something I missing here?

[image: network diagram]

Comment: Are you basically trunking all the of VLANs to the internal interface of the firewall? Or is there some layer-3 routing going on in the switch?

Comment: Yes, trunking to internal interface. No L3 routing happening on the switch

Comment: So the router will need a subinterface for each VLAN on that trunk link, tagged for each VLAN. Does it?

Comment: Yep, at this point we got everything working. We had to create subinterfaces and all, next challenge is the CPU ulitization is spiking as we add more VLANs and interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each VLAN, I needed a default gateway subinterface